# Гистограммы наслаиваются друг на друга

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать цикл, который будет пробегаться по каждому столбцу  и строить на основе каждого гистограмму. Но столбцы наславаются друг на друга....
Помогите понять, пожалуйста, что в моем коде не так?

```
df = pd.read_excel('Proba.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
newdf = df[df.columns[0:6]]

for col in newdf.columns:
        N, bins, patches = pl.hist(newdf[col], bins=[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50],  edgecolor='black')
        jet = pl.get_cmap('Blues', len(patches))
        for i in range(len(patches)):
              patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i))
        plt.savefig("{}.png".format(str(col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы желаете выводить гистограммы в разных окнах, то это, естественно, надо указывать явно. Ну, например так:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(6)
```

А потом строить гистограмму в соответствующем окне:

```
ax[i].hist(....)
```